# How to convert list items to dictionary keys with 0 as default values?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to turn this list:

```
['USA', 'Canada', 'Japan']
```

into this dictionary:

```
{'USA': 0, 'Canada': 0, 'Japan': 0}
```

Can it be achieved with a simple loop? How would you go about it? Thanks!

Comment: `dict.fromkeys(['USA', 'Canada', 'Japan'], 0)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `dict.fromkeys`:

```py
lst = ["USA", "Canada", "Japan"]

out = dict.fromkeys(lst, 0)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'USA': 0, 'Canada': 0, 'Japan': 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), iteratevely appending keys to empty dictionaries:

```
class collections.defaultdict(default_factory=None, /[, ...])
```

> Return a new dictionary-like object. defaultdict is a subclass of the built-in dict class. It overrides one method and adds one writable instance variable.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> lst = ["USA", "Canada", "Japan"]
>>> new = defaultdict(dict)
>>> for x in lst:
...     new[x] = 0
...
>>> new
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'USA': 0, 'Canada': 0, 'Japan': 0})
```